# Куда(,) ты думаешь, он едет?

Tags: запятые, вводные-слова

Нужна ли запятая?

1. Куда(,) ты думаешь, он едет?
2. Куда(,) ты думаешь, что он едет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** *Куда, ты думаешь, он едет?*
В этом предложении "ты думаешь" является вводным сочетанием и выделяется запятыми с двух сторон (можно изъять из предложения: *Куда он едет?*).

Примеры:
*И куда, **ты думаешь,** они летели?..* (В. Железников);
*Куда, **ты думаешь,** он возвращался после всех этих бесконечных скитаний по свету?* (П. Данкер).

**2.** *Куда(,) ты думаешь, что он едет?*
Ни с указанной запятой (Куда, ты думаешь, что он едет?), ни без нее (Куда ты думаешь, что он едет?) предложение не является корректным.

Возможна такая пунктуация:
*Куда ты? Думаешь, что он едет?

Куда? Ты думаешь, что он едет?*

**3.** Из [статьи о вводных конструкциях](https://ruslang.ru/doc/trudy/vol25/Kustova.pdf) Г. И. Кустовой (п. 5):

> Я думаю, что он уже не приедет. → Он, [я] думаю, уже не приедет;
> Ты думаешь, что он уже не приедет? → Он, [ты] думаешь, уже не приедет?

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: *Куда, **ты думаешь**, он едет?*

**Пояснение**

Сравнить: Как ты думаешь, куда он едет?  Это СПП, ***КАК*** — союзное слово.

**Упрощение** в разговорной речи (вводные предложения): *Куда, как ты думаешь, он едет? Куда, ты думаешь, он едет?*

**Некорректная запись**: Куда, ты думаешь, что он едет? (Два союзных слова.)